# A-Frame THREE.TextureLoader loading texture whice is looking whitewashed

Tags: three.js, aframe, texture-mapping

I am updating an a-image scr using THREE.TextureLoader

```
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
const imgload = loader.load(
            './test.png',
              function ( texture ) {
                      firstFrameImage.getObject3D('mesh').material.map = texture
                      firstFrameImage.getObject3D('mesh').material.needsUpdate = true
              },
            
              // onProgress callback currently not supported
              undefined,
            
              // onError callback
              function ( err ) {
                console.error( 'An error happened.' );
              }
            )
```

Its updating the texture but its making the texture whitewashed. Can any one help?

Original image:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTN6m.png)

Updated texture coming as:
[after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ddY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fix this by doing this:

```js
texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

Color deviations like this mostly occur because of wrong color space definitions.